# Site Layout Messes up in Google Chrome, Safariadds

Tags: php, html, css

I have been working on the layout of my site for the past couple of days and you all have been a great help. I noticed that when I open my site with Google Chrome (my primary browser) and Safari as well, the adds in my left side bar aren't aligned with the calendar image I have heading the whole section.

This, however, is not a problem in Firefox. If anyone could point me towards some resources that would help I would very much appreciate it.

My website: http://www.merrimentdesign.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With .crush { width:50px; } works for me in google chrome and firefox. [image]

Is this what you want, the current crushes aligned right with the calendar image, or not?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your image size, 218width x height . Your Tr have 221 width and left side bar tr 221 width too, so in google chrome the image align left in tr and you have 3 pixels in blank.

Put your image with 221 width or change your tables to 218 width.

Comment: my goal is to move the adds over to the left and under the calender image so there is a strip of background between it and the content area (just like the left). It seems my table width for the left column is already 218, though

Comment: I don't know if i understanding what you want, but the TR that holds your calendar image have 221 width , your image have 218x200, and in your divs .crushr your width is 146 and crushl 82 ,these two values are equal to 228px width. Try to put your div .crushl width:75px;

Comment: Essentially, I want to move the Current Crushes over to the left more.

Comment: You Try What I said? If you put your div .crushl width:75px; or less, your current crushes go to the left.